# Question regarding Continuity of F(x,y)

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let
$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{2(x^3+y^3)}{x^2+2y}&\text{ } (x,y)\not=(0,0)\\ 0 &\text{ }(x,y) =(0,0). \end{cases}$
show that first order partial derivatives of $f$ wrt x and y exist at (0,0). Also show that $f$ is not continous at(0,0)

My proceeding so far:
the partial dervatives come out to be as :$f_{x(0,0)}$=2 and $f_{y(0,0)}$=0 (btw what does it imply to have different partial dervatives at a point?)
for continuity i tried paths such as y=m$x^2$, x=m$y^2$, y=m$x^3$and x=m$y^3$ but they all show same limit 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not defined on the parabola $y=-\frac 12x^2$. Thus in order to prove discontinuity at $(0,0)$, you can try the path $y=-\frac 12x^2+x^4$ which gives for $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$:
$$f(x,-\frac 12x^2+x^4)=2\frac{x^3+(-\frac 12x^2+x^4)^3}{2x^4}\sim \frac 1x\to\infty$$
for $x\to 0$.

Comment: thats really unobvious or weird path to choose, from exam point of view

Comment: couldnt it be done by showing function is not differentiable. bcoz if its continous only then will it be differentiable. so, we will show its not differentiable

Comment: Since the function is not continuous at $(0,0)$, it isn't differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Comment: no, i am saying, could discontinuity at (0,0) be proved by showing first that it is not differentiable? since being differentiable requires continuity